# $\int \cos(a)\cos(a+b)\,da$

Tags: integration

I've tried to found the resolution of this integral but I didn't, could you please show me how would you resolve this? 
$$\int \cos(a)\cos(a+b)\,da$$
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use $2\cos(a)\cos(a+b)=\cos(b)+\cos(2a+b)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Since $\cos(a+b)=\cos(a)\cos(b)-\sin(a)\sin(b)$, we have that
$$\int \cos(a)\cos(a+b)\,da=\cos(b)\int \cos^2(a)\,da-\sin(b)\int \cos(a)\sin(a) \, da.$$
Moreover, by the same formula, $\cos(2a)=\cos^2(a)-\sin^2(a)=2\cos^2(a)-1$, which implies that
$$\cos^2(a)=\frac {1+\cos (2a)}{2}.$$
Can you take it from here?

P.S. Alternative approach: use [Prosthaphaeresis Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#The_identities) and transform a product of cosines in a sum of cosines.

Comment: Follow this hint and got to the result I was looking for. Thank you so much for giving me the hint instead of the solution! :)

Comment: @David Barranco Well done!!

Answer (score 3):

HINT: use that $$\cos(a)\cos(a+b)=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(b)+\cos(2a+b))$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

$$\cos (a)\cos (a+b)=$$
$$\sin (b)\cos^2 (a)-\frac {\sin (2a)}{2}\sin (b) $$

and
$$\cos^2(a)=\frac {1+\cos (2a)}{2} $$